# How do I close a nested Material UI dialog box before the parent when I want to close both?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I have a dialog in Material UI that opens a nested progress dialog when fetching data from a web service. Nested dialogs aren't a pattern I like, but client does.

If the fetch succeeds I want to close the progress dialog *and* the parent dialog. If the fetch fails, I close the progress dialog, but keep the parent open.

I'm using Redux, so set flags to close both when the API request completes successfully. These flags are ultimately passed to the dialogs via props.

However, it seems that the parent dialog is rendered before the nested, so it disappears first, quickly followed by the progress dialog. That's a little ugly.

How can I dismiss the child before the parent---or simultaneously with the parent. Either would work---just don't want the child open when the parent is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent dialog closes before the progress dialog, then they are not unmounted in the same rendering cycle meaning a) setting the flags is triggered by two different actions, which are running asynchronously or b) the Material UI dialog closes in a different cycle. I am not familar with Material UI, but in the second case, there is probably something like a onClose hook in the component, which you could use to dispatch an action, which unsets the flag of your main dialog.